# Filtering rows containing two specific words

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter all rows containing two words: `mom` and `dad`.

```
Family
My mom is a teacher. 
My dad is a policeman.
Both my mom and dad are retired.
```

My expected output would be

```
Both my mom and dad are retired
```

as it contains both the words.
I have tried with str.contains(). Just wondering if there is another approach to do it.

```
s = df.Family
searchfor = ['mom', 'dad']
found = [s.str.contains(x) for x in searchfor]
result = pd.DataFrame[found]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.contains` with regex `(?=.*mom)(?=.*dad)`, which will match a string that contains both `mom` and `dad` (this is done by using two look ahead assertions `?=`, i.e. assert the string matches both `.*mom` and `.*dad`):

```
df[df.Family.str.contains(r'(?=.*mom)(?=.*dad)')]
#                               Family
# 2  Both my mom and dad are retired.
```

[Demo Link](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/46826fa5.py)